# 0 validation loss while training TensorFlow CNN model

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network

```html
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import cv2

DATADIR = "C:\\Users\\John\\Documents\\CroppedYale"
CATEGORIES = ["yaleB01","yaleB02","yaleB03","yaleB04","yaleB05","yaleB06","yaleB07","yaleB08","yaleB09","yaleB10","yaleB11","yaleB12","yaleB13","yaleB15","yaleB16","yaleB17","yaleB18","yaleB19","yaleB20","yaleB21","yaleB22","yaleB23","yaleB24","yaleB25","yaleB26","yaleB27","yaleB28","yaleB29","yaleB30","yaleB31","yaleB32","yaleB33","yaleB34","yaleB35","yaleB36","yaleB37","yaleB38","yaleB39"]

for category in CATEGORIES:
    path = os.path.join(DATADIR, category)
    for img in os.listdir(path):
        img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,img), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
        plt.imshow(img_array, cmap="gray")
        plt.show()
        break
    break


print(img_array)

IMG_SIZE = 50
new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE))
plt.imshow(new_array,cmap="gray")
plt.show()

training_data = []

def create_training_data():
    for category in CATEGORIES:
        path = os.path.join(DATADIR, category)
        class_num = CATEGORIES.index(category)
        for img in os.listdir(path):
            try:
                img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,img), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
                new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE))
                training_data.append([new_array, class_num])
            except Exception as e:
                pass
            
            
create_training_data()

print(len(training_data))

import random

random.shuffle(training_data)

for sample in training_data[:10]:
    print(sample[1])

X = []
y = []

for features, label in training_data:
    X.append(features)
    y.append(label)
    
X = np.array(X).reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1)
y = np.array(y)

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D

X = X/255.0


model = Sequential()
model.add( (Conv2D(64 , (3,3) , input_shape = X.shape[1:])))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64 , (3,3)))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation("relu"))

model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation("sigmoid"))

model.compile(loss="CategoricalCrossentropy",
             optimizer="adam",
             metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X, y, batch_size=32, epochs=10, validation_split=0.1)
```

Does anyone know why I get 0.00 loss? Obviously I'm doing something wrong. I just don't know what. It's 40 people with their own folder each folder has 36 images of their face. Is it a problem with how I processed my data or the model itself? Maybe the model has wrong layers or the preprocessing is wrong altogether.

Comment: The architecture of your model seems a bit off. You are trying to categorize the images, but there is only a single output. Instead, the labels should be one-hot encoded, i.e. vectors with a 1 for the corresponding category and 0 otherwise. Then it's also okay to use categorical cross entropy. In your case, it looks more like a regression, mapping the input images to a single number - but with the wrong loss function. How exactly do your labels look like?

Comment: Oh, and also use a softmax activation when dealing with categorical data like this